# Align address_1 and adress_2 fields content in summary email in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to align values from address_1 and address_2 fields from checkout on one level in summary email? Right now I'm getting one under another, which looks odd. This is how I managed to put those fields next to one another in checkout page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'align_address_fieldss_checkout' );
   
function align_address_fieldss_checkout( $fields ) {
  
$fields['address_1']['class'] = array( 'form-row-first' );
$fields['address_2']['class'] = array( 'form-row-last' );
  
return $fields;
}
```

Should I have something similar for email/order summary?

I see there is some [gist](https://gist.github.com/woogists/931aa497fbbdc1061507a61798af5f7f) for adding fields, but is there something similar to editing fields?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve goal in question completely different approach had to be taken. To change order of fields in address I had to use `woocommerce_localisation_address_formats`. In there I can modify number and order of fields as required.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'woocommerce_custom_address_format', 20 );
function woocommerce_custom_address_format( $formats ) {
    $formats[ 'default' ] = "{name}\n{company}\n{address_1} {address_2}\n{city}\n{state}\n{postcode}\n{country}";
    $formats[ 'US' ] = "{name}\n{company}\n{address_1} {address_2}\n{city}, {state_code} {postcode}\n{country}";
     
    return $formats;
}
```